# Google Places Autocomplete, filter by establishments/restaurants

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

I can use the API to search by establishments as shown in their guides(https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete), however I also know that a GMSPlace has a type, which can be a coffee shop/restaurant.

The ios api doesn't seem to have a simple "place search" like the web service does, it's either PlaceID search, or autocomplete.

Can I use the Autocomplete and filter my results based on the type?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GMSAutocompleteFilter](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/reference/interface_g_m_s_autocomplete_filter) to filter out establishment. establishment returns only places that are businesses.

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately it looks like the only way to get the more detailed types is through the web service..