# Google Places API: Is it possible to specify the establishment (using the filter)

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

So on the [Google Places API webpage](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types) it lists a bunch of different types of filters. However, the only filter I've seen that has been used (other than country) is "establishment". Is the webpage outdated? I'm specifically looking to add restaurants. Here is what I have so far:

```
    autoCompleteController.delegate = self
    let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
    filter.type = .establishment
    autoCompleteController.autocompleteFilter = filter
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you sure we are looking at the same documentation? The page you linked clearly states that there is a restaurants filter.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a duplicate of the below link. I don't believe the Places API allows you to restrict further than the establishment filter. At least not for autocomplete.

[Google Places Autocomplete, filter by establishments/restaurants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32638469/google-places-autocomplete-filter-by-establishments-restaurants)